# What tools to use for reporting for Terabyte scale of data in AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

We have data in the range of 100 TeraBytes. We’d need to run pre-defined reports on this data (Not a lot of Adhoc reporting). For the pre-defined reports, the expected turn around time is 10s seconds, should not be in minutes.

We are all AWS server-less so far. The original data source is DynamoDB. What toolset should we use? Is redshift server-less an overkill for this? I hear data should be atleast PB scale to use it.

The 100 Terabytes of data are expected to accumulate in the period of next 5 years.

I have been leaning towards streaming data to S3 and using Athena for querying but the unpredictability of query performance is making us anxious.

Is redshift/ redshift serverless/ spectrum an overkill for this use case?

Any better toolset that I should explore?

Comment: Does it have to be a AWS-only solution?

Comment: @RobertKossendey Yes most-likely but open for altenrate suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Given this light query load but large data and S3 storage of the data I'd go with Redshift serverless with the large data located in S3 and accessed via spectrum.  This will give you the full functionality of Redshift but not paying for a cluster up full time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you mean storing all of the data in S3 and using Spectrum to query it? or storing recent data in redshift, archive old in S3?  Those 2 seem like just extensions of Redshift so does it make more sense to be storing recent information in redshift and others in S3? Also, does our use case/size of data really warrant the use of Redshift? Any specific examples of this architecture that I can follow/

Comment: A typical pattern for spectrum is to store dimensional data locally on the cluster but to access fact data from S3.  Some info on how spectrum works will help here.  Spectrum is best when you can perform computational steps within S3 where a great deal of parallelism can be achieved.  The most important things that can be done within S3 are applying WHERE clauses and performing aggregation.  JOINing and complex analytics have to be done within Redshift.  Dimensional tables are usually smaller and are used in full so make more sense to have within Redshift storage.

Comment: Your use case may vary from this typical case.  If the most recent data is likely to be "hot" and used in full then, yes, storing this on Redshift disks makes sense.  Spectrum gives you 3 things - storage size, greater parallelism, and reduced data transfer size.  Not using all these all of these will result in a less effective use of this tool.  If you are just storing your data in S3 and then have to transfer all of it to Redshift to do anything - you are not getting your money's worth.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to partition your data in S3 - yet another way to reduce data movement work

Answer (score 0):

If you can stream data to S3 and your pre-defined report aggregate on a certain time window (like hour/day/week), I would suggest using a database that creates rollups or materialized views so your query will run fast (that is one of your requirements). With rollups or materialized views, you are looking at a much smaller table to query, saving you money on storage and on compute resources during query time. At the same time, you might want to pay attention to the ease of use and cost of creating rollups or materialized views.

Granted I don't know what your data looks like, but being able to handle things like nested JSON which is common with DynamoDB is probably another important requirement. Some systems can handle nested JSON out of the box and some will require ETL tooling to 'flatten' the data.

Here are a few I know that can do rollups and/or materialized views:

- Rockset
- Druid
- Elasticsearch
- Clickhouse

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much for your response. The data is coming from Dynamo DBs. Here are the things we show in the report:

The data dump of measurements from IoT for the selected period up until the last minute,

Graphs showing the trends and highlighting where the configured thresholds on measurements have crossed.,

Getting the average, min, max, and std on measurements,

Alarms -when did they, when did they end, min and max value in that period, etc.

I plan to partition alarm data by customerId/locationId/YYY/DD/MM/HH

Comment: These events will have to be streamed and stored to s3

An alarm starts at x time ->

Alam ack at y time ->.

The alarm ended at z time

Alarms are on locations that are streaming measurements.

So let;s say part of the report is

"Get all alarms on a location between a and b time where a and b can be as long as 7-10 years"

will athena be performant in this case? Since I cannot update records in S3, what's the best way to store information like this that gets updated frequently like the alarm status but the trail of updates is required to conclude a report?

Comment: With with of the systems I mentioned above there's either a native connector to S3 that can track updates to a certain S3 bucket, or you can use ETL tools to push that into those systems. As you mentioned your data set is really large unless you aggregate it by time buckets. If your IoT device for example send data every second or several times every second than aggregating by an hour would reduce your data by at least 60x. You can see an example of how you aggregate by the hour in Rockset here (https://rockset.com/docs/rollups/).

Comment: I don't think any system can give yous seconds latency without some sort of aggregation. There are many ways to go about this also depending on how hands-on you want to be. Maintaining an ETL pipeline is not easy, so personally I would prefer something that works without one. 
I'm not experience with Athena but I doubt it can give you seconds query latency on such a large dataset. You really want a database built for analytics. You most likely be using a columnar index, so all the systems I mentioned above should either build one for you or let you create one.